# Is it possible to have a one-cent-per-year salary in the United States?

Tags: united-states, salary

I'm aware of [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=One-dollar_salary&oldid=970941244#Notable_one-dollar_salary_earners) [people](https://www.salary.com/personal/executive-salaries/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812222534/https://www.salary.com/personal/executive-salaries/)) earning in a [one-dollar salary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-dollar_salary), and I'm not aware of anyone earning in a one-cent salary. Is it possible to have a one-cent-per-year salary in the United States?

I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=One-dollar_salary&oldid=970941244) that:

> One-dollar salaries are used in situations where an executive wishes to work without direct compensation, but **for legal reasons must receive a payment above zero**, so as to distinguish him or her from a volunteer.

so I wonder if the minimum is 0.01 USD or 1 USD.

Comment: Not only am I willing to hire you for a salary of one cent per year but I'm also willing to pay you time and a laugh.

Comment: @BobBaerker as long as the laugh isn't taxable I'll take it.

Comment: For federal tax purposes we round to the nearest dollar, so 0.01 would round to 0. I don't know if that is the reason $1 is used instead of $0.01. Is that $0.99 difference significant in some context? I don't see why it would matter.

Comment: @HartCO To see whether Bob can hire me at that price, and more generally to understand the implications of such a salary.

Comment: "Possible" in the sense of "sure, it's technically legal but it's going to screw up a few dozen automated systems/ tax instructions/ other bureaucratic processes that either round or truncate the cents and require lawyers and accountants and other functionaries to argue about the difference between what the law allows and what the process allows"?  Or "possible" in the sense of "what any sane employer would let you do"?

Comment: 1 Dollar - one of the base accounting unit - is not only used in case of salatirs and is basically an accounting default. Machine written off? It is in the book with - guess what - 1 USD. If anything, I would argue the 1 USD is a convention. And makes no practical difference. It is not like you pay anything more or less on a 1 cent salary.

Comment: Does anyone **actually know** if it is **technically legal**.  All I see is speculation.

Comment: @Fattie speculations and downvotes? Sounds like we're on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 6):

I'm speculating because I don't know what legal reasons would be at play here, but my assumption is that it is either tax related, or that the primary means for proving employee status are tax records. If that assumption holds, the IRS policy of rounding to the nearest dollar would necessitate a pay that rounds to $1 instead of $0.

That makes you wonder if they could then just pay $0.51 so that it rounds to $1. Even if that were the case, my guess is that a nice even dollar is just easier.

A $1 salary in the context of minimum wage/minimum salary laws is certainly legal for [business owners](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fact-sheets/17b-overtime-executive):

> Under a special rule for business owners, an employee who owns at
> least a bona fide 20-percent equity interest in the enterprise in
> which employed, regardless of the type of business organization (e.g.,
> corporation, partnership, or other), and who is actively engaged in
> its management, is considered a bona fide exempt executive.

That means a business owner can be an exempt employee (no minimum wage/overtime requirement) without meeting the other criteria (minimum salary) that apply to exempt employees.

This [Business Insider article](https://www.businessinsider.com/ceos-who-take-1-dollar-salary-or-less-2015-8#mark-zuckerberg-5) from last year highlights a number of CEO's who are/were receiving salary of $1 or less. On the list are several that don't own 20% of their companies, which supports the notion that there are other exceptions to the minimum salary rule, but based on the [DOL sheet](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fact-sheets/17b-overtime-executive) linked above I don't see what specifically would apply to non-owners.

Comment: Thanks, good point about the potential rounding complicated.

Comment: Does anyone actually know if it is technically legal. All I see is speculation.

Comment: I like that addition about classifying an owner as a "bona fide exempt executive". I interpret it to mean "exempt" from minimum wage, overtime, and hourly regulations, but I don't see where it exempts them from the minimum salary under 29 CFR 514. Still digging -- this is becoming a fun little rabbit-hole. :-)

Comment: @DougDeden You'll notice in the link that the rules for exempt executives includes a salary requirement, but the special rule for business owners does not have that requirement. They get to be an exempt executive regardless of salary.

Comment: I hate trying to read government language, but I still think it exempts owners from the same things that the other exempt categories (management, administrative, professional, computer, outside sales) cover, but not from part 541. But I don't really have a leg to stand on here. I'll see if I can find another document that words it in a way that makes more sense to me. (I'm not saying that your interpretation is wrong -- I'm just seeing some language that could go your way or mine, and trying to find a way to get past the ambiguity that I perceive.)

Comment: @DougDeden If all the requirements for "executive exemption" applied to business owners anyway, there would be no point in adding that special business owner section. I agree though, tax code and gov-speak is brutal.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Hart CO's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/129800) about rounding and tax implications. But I'm gonna come at this from another direction.

## Even one dollar per year *might* not be legal

A case can be made to challenge the legality of the one-dollar-per-year salary. The US Department of Labor (DOL) sets a minimum salary for exempt employees. [Beginning on 01 January 2020](https://www.wagehourinsights.com/2019/09/new-minimum-salary-for-exempt-employees-takes-effect-january-1-2020/), this minimum is $23,660 annually. In this context, "exempt" primarily means exempt from receiving overtime pay.

So if the employee in question is exempt, they would not be able to receive a salary of one dollar per year without violating that DOL rule. On the other hand, if they are non-exempt, they would be subject to the more well-known minimum wage -- currently $7.25 per hour in the US, and higher in some jurisdictions. Plus, they'd be subject to hour tracking and overtime. (I suspect most of these are senior executives, and they probably work well over 40 hours per week.) Most wage and hour regulations round to the nearest 15-minute increment, and have a minimum number of paid hours per shift. Even if the minimum is fifteen minutes, that's $1.81 even if the employee in question only worked 15 minutes in the entire year.

Per the Wikipedia article linked in the question, many recent or current situations of this phenomenon are government employees. Perhaps the DOL regulations don't apply to government employees -- I haven't found anything on that yet.

## The special case of the U.S. President

In the specific case of the president, the [U.S. Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution) sets forth that the president is to receive a fixed salary, and then [3 U.S. Code § 102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/102) currently has it set at $400,000 per year. That's why President Trump couldn't opt for zero (or one dollar per year) and instead is donating his salary to various organizations.

Comment: I seem to remember another DOL rule to the effect that wages must be paid no less frequently than once a month, and so one cent per year would be impossible, but one cent per month might be legitimate.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Interesting. I've found this -- https://www.patriotsoftware.com/blog/payroll/pay-frequency-requirements-state-federal/# -- which says that while there is no federal requirement, 47 states plus DC require monthly or more frequent pay. So that penny per year might still be on the table for Alabama, Florida, and South Carolina. :-)

Comment: The exempt employee rules that require a minimum salary don't apply to business owners at the least, so $1 is certainly legal for those folks.